# Service Fabric ServiceManifest parameterization Traefik Reverse Proxy

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

In my ServiceManifest I have the following configuration:

```
<ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Web1Type">
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule.hostname">Host: test.staal-it.nl#</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.expose">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>
```

I would like to be able to replace test.staal-it.nl with a parameter from an ApplicationParameters file to make changes when I deploy this app to another environment. However, as far as I can see there's no override xml element available for Extension. How can this be done. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema for the schema definition

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, is not possible to use replacement values on extensions, it might be in future releases.

The Extensions was an workaround to integrate Traefik with service fabric.

According to Traefik [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/servicefabric/#property-manager), you can set these values via [SF REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-v60-api-updateservice)

[This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/04/05/intelligent-routing-on-service-fabric-with-traefik/) post also gives a nice overview on how to use traefik on SF

The other approach you could take is using the traefik [REST API](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/rest/#api): if you have control on your services, your service startup could call the traefik api and register itself, you would then add the settings to your service configuration like you would with normal settings.

Comment: Using the rest api isn't going to work since I could only call that after a complete rolling update meaning that during the update my staging environment would listen to a wrong hostname

Comment: if  you prefer the settings approach, you could make your service register on traefik using rest api, i've added extra info + link

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to using a parameter file, and if you use a release tool like VSTS, you can use a [tokenizer](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) to replace things for different environments. Or, on Linux, you could use something like [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) + environment variables.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Using a tokenizer to replace both the host name in the ServiceManifest and replacing the ApplicationTypeName in the ApplicationManifest during deployment in VSTS. Not ideal but it works